# Multiple table row sort

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to implement the *sortable* feature to an *html table* using *jquery-ui* and I came across an issue.

I need to be able to sort a set of rows belonging to specific topics and sort the rows within that topic as-well. I have done a sample as follows,

[What I have for now - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wasjk8x/2/)

But my concern is how can I allow the items within the topics to be sortable. Currently its sorts only the main topics and you experts' help on this greatly appreciated.

P.S. - I put this together by studying these two samples, [Sample 1 - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmw57/tzYbU/205/), [Sample 2 - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PM6nv/16/)

Please excuse if this is a simple question. I am a bit new to this area of development.

Comment: you want both sortable main topic & items within topic?

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura yes.. I want the topics to be sortable as a whole which i have now, and the items within the topics to be able to sort also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have did few changes into html & JavaScript see in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siddhapura/9wasjk8x/3/)

JavaScript Code

```
$("#sort > tbody").sortable({
    items: 'tr:not(.head)'
}).disableSelection();
$("#sort").sortable({
    items: 'tbody:has(tr)'
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer +1 :) the solution works .. but is this the proper way to do it ?

Comment: @Hasitha Yes it is. (if it working fine then select as answer)